# How can I contribute source code to the NTP project?

Tags: contributor

Can someone please explain how to contribute code to the [NTP project](http://www.ntp.org/)? They do have a [github repository](https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp), but it does not seem very up-to-date, with only one branch. They also have a [bitkeeper repository](https://bk.ntp.org/), with two branches `ntp-dev` and `ntp-stable`. It's a little more up-to-date (15 months old). Also why is the stable **newer** than the development branch. Seems kind of odd.

Comment: How did you try to contact them and what was their reply and answer when you approached them with these questions?

Answer (score 6):

The internal dynamics of a project are their own business. I've seen some that only publish stable versions on github (or such), others that are just distributed as tarballs (and you can send patches to the maintainer). Some, like TeX (used to) be handled just by the lead developer, who collected bug reports and proposed patches, and took a look at what has accumulated some few years apart. A development branch that is abandoned while the stable/main branch marches on is not unheard of. There is no (can't be, really) any general rule applicable to all projects, from my own small for-fun, just local ones to huge international collaborations like the Linux kernel, with company-internal developments with their own dynamics in between. Some packages just are "done", the relevant standards haven't changed in quite some time, and all bugs (ha!) have already been tracked down and fixed by now, for others there just is no interest in working on them anymore. Sometimes a new group clones an abandoned (or almost) project and marches on, often (but not always) under a new name.